# drop down menu on mouseout should remain visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, onmouseover, onmouseout

The button with dropdown menu should be visible when the mouse is moved inside the div which works fine but the problem is that when I move the mouse out of that div, I want the button and dropdown menu to remain visible if menu is dropped down but the button should get hidden if menu is not dropped down.How can I achieve this?(in the given code, button and dropdown menu get hidden on mouseout no matter what)

```
<div id="img_container" name="img_container" onmouseover="f()" onmouseout ="g()">
            <img src="image/images.jpg"  alt="Cover" >
            <div class="btn-group" id="cov" name="cov" >
               <button  class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Action
               </button>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <!-- dropdown menu links -->
                <li><a href="#">Secondary link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another link</a></li>
               </ul>
            </div>
        </div>


function f(){
      document.getElementById("cov").style.display="inline-block";
  }

  function g(){
      document.getElementById("cov").style.display="none";
  }
```

***[`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/KzfYe/)***

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: css it with a hover, and do an outside click option.

Comment: @Placeholders_in_use Can you please elaborate about it?

Comment: http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/

Comment: A CSS `:hover` will revert when the mouse exits the element it is attached to... I think the OP wants it to remain only in a certain circumstance so a logic has to be written in...

Comment: Are you trying to do a time based flipper sliding menu, because that's a little more difficult to do.  took me about 3 hours to figure out while reteaching myself JavaScript.

Comment: no..not time-based flipper..however is there any way by which we can know if menu is dropped down..then all this becomes too easy

Comment: please rephrase your question its a bit confusing and if you are trying achieve some other sits functionality then give that as example as proper example helps in quick solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly you want something like this:

```
var list = document.getElementById("dropdown-menu");
var menu = document.getElementById("cov");

function dropdown() {
    if (list.style.display == "none") {
        list.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        list.style.display = "none";
    }
}

function f() {
    menu.style.display = "block";
}

function g() {
    if (list.style.display == "none") {
        menu.style.display = "none";
    } else if (list.style.display == "block"){
        menu.style.display = "block";
    } else {menu.style.display = "block"}
}
```

Here is a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/brewersomething/KzfYe/50/)

Comment: Good solution, this exactly answers the question!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of set the `style` to display `none`, use the `.show()` and `.hide()` in `jquery` to show and hide the specific `div`

```
$('#cov').hide();

function f() {
    //document.getElementById("cov").style.display = "inline-block";
    $('#cov').show();
}

function g() {
    // $('#cov').hide();
   //document.getElementById("cov").style.display = "none";
}
```

[JSFiddle to show div when mouse over](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/KzfYe/3/)

Comment: you are asking for hiding the `button` if the menu is not drop down. But you already have your menu inside the `html`. It means, it will forever drop down and you forever can not hide the button

Answer (score 0):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sid_m/KzfYe/1/), hope this is what you are looking for.

You don't need `onmouseout ="g()"`

**Update**

try this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sid_m/KzfYe/52/)

Comment: when i mouseout I want the button to hide if menu is not dropped down

Comment: in this firstly, the button gets hidden onclick when the menu is dropped down but I want the button to remain visible on clicking it and secondly it works for only one time